# Dynamic Import Error Firebase Cloud Functions Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

im trying to make a flutter app that uses flutter cloud functions as the backend. Whenever I try to `npm run serve` I get this issue... has anyone seen this before? Im new to cloud functions but it doesnt make sense to me to use the dynamic import... thanks!

```
✔  functions: Using node@18 from host.
⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module myapp/functions/node_modules/chatgpt/build/index.js from myapp/functions/lib/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of myapp/node_modules/chatgpt/build/index.js in myapp/functions/lib/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

```
➜  functions node --version
v18.15.0
➜  functions firebase --version
11.25.1
```

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like **Firebase Cloud Functions** uses `CommonJS` modules, while **chatgpt library** you are importing uses `ECMAScript` modules.
In order to fix it change your code from:

```
const chatgpt = require('chatgpt');
```

to:

```
const chatgpt = await import('chatgpt');
```

Comment: Wow that was it! I am using typescript, is there an easier way to do this? 
I cant use top level awaits either so I had to await chatgpt in the call.

Comment: there are multiple ways to import it without top awaits. Use **IFF**: `(async () => { const chatgpt = await import('chatgpt'); })();` Another example using an old **then-catch** example: `import('chatgpt').then(module => {  /* Use the module here */  }).catch(error => {  /* Handle errors here */  });`